# overlapping dependencies in node.js

Tags: node.js

If I need to require an npm module that is already installed as a sub dependency to another module, should I still install it with npm?

For instance, kue requires redis so red is is installed with kue e.g.
    npm install kue

```
/node_modules/kue/node_modules/redis
```

should I still install redis as well, thus npm install redis

```
/node_modules/redis/
```

or is there a way I can add a reference to the redis installed from kue in my require statements

```
require("/node_modules/kue/node_modules/redis")
```

instead of

```
require ("redis")
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general rule of thumb:

If you `require('module-name')` in your application's source code, you should list `module-name` as a dependency.  Treat dependencies of dependencies as opaque implementation details, and don't concern yourself with them.

This allows kue to depend on a different redis module version than your application, or switch out its implementation for a different module entirely.  All without affecting your application.

Node's module system is different than "conventional" one (e.g. Ruby), in that multiple versions of the same module can be loaded in the same process without causing a conflict.  This feels a bit off at first, but just go with it and you'll see benefits quickly.  I suspect that as the community explores this aspect of Node further, we'll see some interesting projects arise to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just install redis locally.

What if you want a different version of redis then the one installed with kue? What if the version of redis abruptly changes when you update the version of kue?

You really shouldn't care about the content of node_modules as long as `require(module)` works as expected. Saving a few kbs of source code is not worth this effort.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't care about installing the modules and dependencies yourself, let [NPM](http://npmjs.org) do that for you.

Also it's not that great to have just one installation of Redis for example, since Kue (or other module depending on Redis) might require a specific version and some other module may require another version.

Let [NPM](http://npmjs.org) do all the work for you, just `npm install package` and then `require('package')` in you code. As @Raynos said, saving a few kbs of code isn't that much of a deal and could get you even into problems.